# Prevent App Crash incase image renamed / deleted from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set logo image in my UIImageView & runs and it's working fine, but in case someone removed / renamed image by mistake then & runs again and my app crashes because Xcode can't find that image.
Here I need to implement that if such images are not found by Xcode due to renamed / removed then its not crashed but some placeholder image should be set & it's globally too in project for all the UIImageViews.
So could anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just use UIImage(named:) instead of `Image Literal`

Comment: I suggest you just remove the whole asset from the catalogue (not just single images from it like shown in the screenshot) and then add it back. That usually does the job for me. No need to use `UIImage(named: "")` or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Quoc Nguyen is correct. You can just use image literal name. Like so:

```
private lazy var logoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "swift_logo"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
```

The `UIImageView` initialiser method can take an **optional** `UIImage` object:

```
init(image: UIImage?)
```

And the `UIImage` initialiser method using name produces **optional** `UIImage` object.

```
init?(named name: String)
```

That means, you can use it safely. Regardless if your logo exists or not. I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

You can make your own extension of `UIImage` class to declare your assets, so that when time comes that you need to rename an asset, you'll have to rename it once and the changes will be applied all throughout your project (globally, as you say).

```
import UIKit

/// A category for handling images
extension UIImage {

    // MARK: - Home Assets

    static let swiftLogo = UIImage(named: "swift_logo") 
}
```

and you can use that like so:

```
private lazy var logoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: .swiftLogo)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
```

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen tnx & u both r correct, but I want that it's working Globally in project with all UIImageView mean something different handy if possible..

Comment: See my updated answer. I hope that helps. Don't forget to select an answer to close your question.